# Create custom field key upon theme activation

Tags: custom-field, metabox

Upon theme activation I want to create an 'URL' key for the custom fields. Like in [image: this screenshot].

I know who to run functions when a theme is activated, I don't know how to create this custom field key though. Any thoughts? I don't want to be using custom meta boxes.

Comment: Please show us how you "run functions when a theme is activated" (in code). Thank you.

Comment: @kaiser if (isset($_GET['activated']) && is_admin()){ }

Comment: See [Is there a way to set default custom fields when creating a post?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/29355/11761).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those values are populated from the unique keys in the `*_postmeta` table, excluding keys that begin with an underscore (`_`). If you want to pre-populate that key the add a value to the table under post ID `0`. There is no way to pre-populate those that I am aware of besides to add a dummy meta_key/value to the `*_postmeta` table.

`add_post_meta('0','URL','');` does not work, at least not when I try, so you need to write the SQL.

```
$wpdb->query("INSERT INTO {$wpdb->postmeta} (post_id,meta_key) values (0,'URL')");
```

That will create numerous entries in the database, however, unless you take further steps to avoid it.

**I strongly advise against this hack.**

Using a custom meta box is by far the cleaner solution, and I cannot guarantee that there are no negative consequences to adding a dummy key/value to `*_postmeta`. I highly recommend that you reconsider the custom meta box option.