# How to add a default field Name to post Custom Fields

Tags: custom-field

I would like to have the "Name" field in the Custom Fields section of of Wordpress backend to have a certain value by default.

For example, when the user starts a new post, I would like the Name of the custom field to be automatically set to "preferred_post_color" like so:

[image: Custom_Field_Image]

The key Name therefore serves as a prompt for the user to enter the value, say, "Red".

Thanks.

Comment: This is already answered very well [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29355/is-there-a-way-to-set-default-custom-fields-when-creating-a-post), please take a look and you should be good to go :)

Comment: I would [add my own meta box](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) and eliminate the potential for user error.

Comment: @ItsMePN: Apart from having a million answers (which one is right for me?), that question is not really exactly the same as mine.

Comment: @Milo: Thank you for the suggestion. I'm actually taking a long look at that option.