# Is there a way to set default custom fields when creating a new post?

Tags: custom-field, customization

When I'm creating a new post, just after clicking "Add New", when the post editor shows, instead of having to use the dropdown and choose a custom field to use, I'd like to have some default custom field inputs already opened.

None of the codes from [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29355/is-there-a-way-to-set-default-custom-fields-when-creating-a-post) worked for me

:3

Answer (score 1):

you can do that better with install advanced custom fileds plugins or any plugin and specify the custom field to all posts , you can install [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/)

or by your simple codes in [wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) and choose one

Comment: I was hoping to do this without plugins.. and none of the codes there suffice ..