# two custom fields question

Tags: custom-field

Two questions

1. [I need an updated code for this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29355/is-there-a-way-to-set-default-custom-fields-when-creating-a-post)
2. How can I hide the value if there is no value entered?

My value would be a link, and this is my current code

```
<a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mp3_link1', true); ?>" target="_blank">MP3</a>
```

**I need to do this without any plugins.**

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0) for SE to distribute that content. By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post, consider taking a look at: [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do to hide this link is to check, if it's empty:

```
<?php if ( $link = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mp3_link1', true) && trim($link) ) : ?>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_attr($link); ?>" target="_blank">MP3</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```